# Switching between Java versions for the same version

Tags: java, macos, graalvm

I want to make some experiments with GradleVM, so I installed the the next java versions on MacOS

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    17.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 17.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.17 (x86_64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 11.0.17" /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.17 (x86_64) "GraalVM Community" - "GraalVM CE 22.3.0" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-22.3.0/Contents/Home
```

I can easily switch between v11 and v17 with the approach

```
alias java-17="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17`; java -version"
alias java-11="export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`; java -version"
```

But how I can switch between GraalVM11 and normal jdk11?

Comment: You could use https://sdkman.io/ Switching between different vendors and versions can be easily done by command line. I have been using it for years on macos and it perfectly run as expected!

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't have the needed versions, so I like to install the versions from the source zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found it much simpler to use sdkman.
It is possible to select there all the versions.

As a bonus you can use `.sdkmanrc` file in your projects. So once you enter the folder you can switch the java version, which you want to use. That saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

`alias graalvm-11="export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-22.3.0/Contents/Home; java -version"`

I've taken the path to GraalVM installation from the output of `java_home -V`

Comment: For me it gives `.zshrc:14: permission denied: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-22.3.0/Contents/Home`

Comment: Maybe this tip taken from their [download page](https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-22.3.0) helps: "If you are using macOS Catalina and later you may need to remove the quarantine attribute from the bits before you can use them. To do this, run the following: `$ sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine path/to/graalvm/folder/`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help